# A Little Explanation About Chat Application

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I am planning to create a chat application that will be used by thousands of users. Initially I have done a lot of tutorials on the net and read many things about PHP and MySQL chat applications.  During this search I have come across many people saying that chat applications in PHP are good for thousands of users. Most of them suggested using NodeJS. The problem I have here is that none of those posts stated why NodeJS is good.

From all the PHP chat tutorials I read, it seems that during the chat sessions between two users, the messages that they are exchanging are sent forth and back to the database. My questions are:

1. In NodeJS, are the messages not sent forth and back to the database?
2. Does NodeJS save the chat messages in memory or something like that?
3. How does it do it differently from PHP and MySQL?
4. Or does NodeJS not use databases at all?

Can someone help me to understand how chat applications work in NodeJS?

I am not asking for code snippets. I want explanation in words. I know there are many tutorials around about NodeJS but am asking specifically concerning chat applications. Your explanation will help me to understand certain things better.

Comment: Node.js is a ligther alternative to PHP+Apache (that's probably why it's being recommended for an app with potential to generate a lot of traffic). Whether you'll be using a database or not, is up to you in both cases (php or node).

Comment: this might be of interest http://www.webappers.com/2012/06/12/open-source-chat-rooms-web-application-with-node-js/

Comment: @Baba, Brian etc..  WHAT IS WRONG WITH THIS POST? Can anyone of you guys who closed this question point to me which part of the question incites arguments. I asked a simple question that someone explain to me why NodeJS is good for chat application and you closed the question. Do i have control over what somebody says? If you think someone's comment brings argument why don't you delete that comment. IT IS VERY DUMMY ON YOUR SIDE TO CLOSE THIS POST. WHAT IS WRONG WITH THE QUESTION I ASKED? Delete the comments that has nothing to do with the post and let the post stands instead of closing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between PHP and Node.js, is that Node.js supports multithreading, and events.

In PHP, you'll have to periodically ping the server for new messages, *each user* would need to do so.

In Node.js, you can implement a smarter solution. Where the client ping the server once, and only gets a response when a new message is received. After that, you ping again.

That reduces server-load immensely, and allows you to handle more users simultaneously.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski That is not multithreading. That is multiprocess.

Comment: @DaveRandom Ok. Maybe not clusters, but [`libuv`](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) is multithreading. It's only for asynchronous APIs implemented in [C/C++](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), but it's not an absolute "*no*."

Comment: You can implement log polling in php also. It's not unique to node.js. Socket.io just makes it really easy.

Comment: Yup, part of being a programmer is choosing the right tool for the job. Jon Skeet can implement such a feature in assembly, writing code only in MS Paint, doesn't mean we should all try it.